# Clear the crash log from XCode's debug navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

When you open `crashlog.crash` in `Xcode`, it shows up in `Debug Navigator`. And when you run , it points you to the place where it crashed. 
This highlights your code in red, at the place where it is crashed.
Now, once I am done with this, I want it to be removed from Xcode. It keeps highlighting the crashed part, and the only way to get rid of it is quit XCode. 
Is there any other way to get rid of the crashlog, after being done with it, without quitting the XCode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just select the crash item you want to delete in the debug navigator and then strike `delete` on the keyboard.

Comment: Oh man, I’ve been right-clicking for years, hoping they added a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Clear All Issues

From the `Product` menu at the top, select `Clear All Issues`.

---

**Delete some**

Select the issue and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> button on the keyboard.